# kubectl does not have config changed when gcloud config changes for Google Cloud Platform project

Tags: google-cloud-platform, kubernetes, gcloud, kubectl

I switched the project config for `gcloud` using `gcloud config set project abcxyz`, however `kubectl get pods` is returning the pods in the previous gcloud / kubernetes project.

How do I update the project config to match gcloud's config?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After you've changed project, run:

```
gcloud container clusters get-credentials <cluster_name>
```

gcloud will then set kubectl to be looking at your new project.